# Rational numbers' test got warning '11/12 != 11/12'

Tags: python, class

I am trying to practice with how to write classes and methods with Python, the content of this exercise is to add/sub/mul/div rational numbers. I got the correct output with the main() block. However, I got the following warning with test file:

```
RationalTest: test_plusminus
11/12 != 11/12 : Incorrect result for operation 1/4 + 2/3!
```

I checked my `__str__` method and did not find a mistake there. Have spend long here but could not find the error. Therefore I pasted codes here to ask for help. Thank you in advance.

Attached are my codes:

```
class Rational(object):
    def __init__(self, nu, denom):
        self.nu = nu
        self.denom = denom
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.nu) + '/' + str(self.denom)

    def __mul__(self, p):
        new_numerator = self.nu * p.nu
        new_denominator = self.denom * p.denom
        return Rational(new_numerator, new_denominator)
    
    def __truediv__(self, p):
        new_param = Rational(p.denom, p.nu)
        return self.__mul__(new_param)

    def __add__(self, p):
        new_denominator = self.denom * p.denom
        new_numerator = self.nu*p.denom + p.nu*self.denom
        return Rational(new_numerator, new_denominator)

    def __sub__(self, p):
        new_denominator = self.denom * p.denom
        new_numerator = self.nu*p.denom - p.nu*self.denom
        return Rational(new_numerator, new_denominator)

    def __gt__(self, p):
        return self.nu*p.denom > self.denom*p.nu
    
    def __lt__(self, p):
        return self.nu*p.denom < self.denom * p.nu

def main():
    r1=Rational(1,4)
    r2=Rational(2,3)
    print(r1)
    print(r2)
    print(r1*r2)
    print(r1/r2)
    print(r1+r2)
    print(r1-r2)
    print(Rational(1,2) == Rational(2,4))
    print(Rational(1,2) > Rational(2,4))
    print(Rational(1,2) < Rational(2,4))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Attached are the part of the test method:

```
def test_plusminus(self):
        r1=Rational(1,4)
        r2=Rational(2,3)
        self.assertEqual(r1+r2, Rational(11,12), msg="Incorrect result for operation %s + %s!" % (r1,r2))
        self.assertEqual(r1-r2, Rational(-5,12), msg="Incorrect result for operation %s - %s!" % (r1,r2))
```

Comment: You forgot to define `__eq__` so no instances of `Rational` will ever be equal.

Comment: You might want to post this to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ as well

Comment: Thank you! I add `def __eq__(self, p):` and `return self.nu == p.nu and self.denom == p.denom`, then it works!

Answer (score 2):

You are not implementing equality, therefore you inherit the default implementation which tests whether two objects are *the same single identical object*.

You should override the equality operator (magic method [`__eq__`](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel#object.__eq__)) with a version that checks for *value equality*.

Alternatively, or in addition, you could make sure that the same rational actually *is* the same object. This would save memory and object allocation, but add complexity to your implementation. You would probably need some sort of `WeakMap` to cache the objects.

Note, you should also implement [`__hash__`](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel#object.__hash__) properly as well, otherwise you will get the same surprise again, when you try to use a rational in a set or as a dict key.

Note that there are some other problems with your implementation as well. For example, you never simplify rationals, so you are treating <sup>1</sup>∕<sub>2</sub> and <sup>2</sup>∕<sub>4</sub> as completely unrelated numbers.